I want my flutter container to have similar kind of squirecircle ui like on css

i am trying to create similar squircle box on flutter like css but no option to change top-center, botom-center, left-center and right-center border. is there any workaround to do so.
no option to achieve similar results.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class frostedGlassBox extends StatelessWidget {
  const frostedGlassBox({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22), color: Colors.amber),
    );
  }
}


Flutter provide a way to clip a widget's borders which appears like continuous rectangle border.
If you seek a smooth clip, there are some packages that provide that. look at that answer

If you care about the shadows on the borders you could use a card like this:
 SizedBox(
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                child: Card(
                  elevation: 10,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22),
                  ),
                  color: Colors.amber,
                  child: Align(alignment: Alignment.center, child: Text("Square", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)),
                ),
              ),

